# Apache HSTS with non-www to www 301 redirect

Tags: 301-redirect, www

Just been setting up HSTS on an Apache vHost (it is a virtualmin box) and have that working, however I am experiencing strange behavior when trying to force a call to https www rather than it redirecting to the https non www.

If I call the http www version then HSTS does its job just fine and gives me the HTTPS, non www site. However manually calling HTTPS WWW throws me a certificate error stating the name on the cert does not match the calling URL.... which I know is because I don't have www on the cert.

I have tried the usual 301 redirect in the vhost but I can still get to 
https www. rather than being redirected to https non www.

Any ideas folks?

Tom

Comment: The SSL handshake is done before the client gets the redirect. If you want a redirect on https you need a certificate for all involved domains. There is no way around it.

Comment: Fix the certificate. It should have all relevant names.